# Restrict symbolic link deletion

Tags: linux, filesystems, bsd

/etc/test.conf is a symbolic link to /var/etc/test.conf.

/var/etc/test.conf file has flags sunlnk and schg, meaning file can not be removed/moved and no modifications allowed (read-only).

Without changing file flags:

- I can NOT delete /var/etc/test.conf AND can NOT modify /var/etc/test.conf.
- I CAN delete /etc/test.conf but can NOT modify /etc/test.conf.

Is there any way in which we can deny /etc/test.conf (symbolic link) deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you're not achieving the results you're after because using the flag on the symlink actually sets it on the target file.

You can try `chflags -h` to to apply the flags to the symlink itself.

```
chflags -h sunlink,schg /etc/test.conf
```